# elasticsearch query on single array item

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have a document in elasticsearch that looks like the following:

```
{
  "_id" : 1
  "sentences" : [
    "The cat lives in Chicago",
    "The dog lives in Milan",
    "The pig lives in Mexico"
  ]
}
```

How can I perform a search / query which will only match if all conditions are met in the same sentence?

I would like to search `sentences:(+Chicago +cat)` I would get a match, but if I searched `sentences:(+Mexico +dog)` I want to get **no** match.

Comment: have you tried taking a look at nested_type for this.

Comment: I agree with @user3775217: you probably need `sentences` to be a `nested` field. Otherwise Elasticsearch will look at the values in `sentences` and will not be able to "distinguish" between the different sentences.

Comment: Thanks I was able to accomplish it with a nested type, with one caveat: the nested type cannot be a string, it must be turned into an array of [{"s":"Key Value Pair Objects"}]